# clone postgres database with new name

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I have a `users-production` database on `157.157.35.333`

I would like to clone it to another host as `users-sandbox`

here is what I tried:

```
    PRODUCTION_HOST=111.111.11.111
    SANDBOX_HOST=222.222.22.222

    echo "creating db on sanbox"
    psql -h ${SANDBOX_HOST} -U postgres  -c "CREATE DATABASE \"users-sandbox\";"

    pg_dump -h ${PRODUCTION_HOST} -U postgres  -d users-production -F c -b -v  | \
       pg_restore -C -c -h ${SANDBOX_HOST} -U postgres  -d users-sandbox -v
```

but this creates the database with the old name

how do I create with a new name?

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html

> -d dbname
>
> Connect to database dbname and restore directly into the database.

but!

> -C
>
> --create
>
> Create the database before restoring into it. If --clean is also
>   specified, drop and recreate the target database before connecting to
>   it.
>
> When this option is used, the **database named with -d is used only to
>   issue the initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE commands. All data
>   is restored into the database name that appears in the archive**.

so remove `-C` from `pg_restore` arguments...

(formatting of quotes mine)